# Can we have a "week" option for the membership type duration unit?

Tags: civimember, payment-processor, recurring-contributions, auto-renew

I'm doing some work to enable the purchase of auto-renewing memberships, using the UK-focussed GoCardless direct debit system.
So far so good. One thing we've noticed is that the GoCardless API understands intervals in weeks, months, and years (with 1 year being the maximum). However CiviCRM's membership type duration unit doesn't offer 'week' as an option.

What would be involved in order to add 'week' as an option here?

Comment: It would be a core change extending the year/month logic to work for week as well - probably not a lot of work.  But I'm curious about the use case here: where would a weekly membership be useful?

Comment: Well, to be honest the value for me right now is in testing: to test effectively with the payment processor I need to let it go through an entire cycle: create DD mandate, take first payment, take renewal payment, ensure that membership is renewed. With a monthly membership as the shorted option supported by both Civi and GoCardless, I have to sit and wait for it to complete.

Comment: Having said that I don't see why there aren't perfectly valid use cases for a weekly payment cycle: off the top of my head: a weight-watcher club for example, or indeed any group that has a weekly meeting cycle. Of course the existing 'day' option could theoretically cope with that, but GoCardless doesn't do 'days'.

Answer (score 1):

We could do an extension for you, consistent with LExIM strategy, to implement this, Graham. Ping me at joe dot murray at jmaconsulting dot biz.